# Expected identifier when parsing expression, got 'nil'

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local httpService = game :GetService("HttpService")
local laber = script.Parent.SurfaceGui.TextLabel
local   URL = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"
local   Data = httpService:GetAsync(URL)

local randomJokes = httpService:JSONDecode(Data)

nil.Text = randomJokes.value
```

Comment: `nil` is a keyword, you can't use it as a variable. Also, where did you define it? It would crash anyways.

Comment: Don't just give us just the error and the code, we need to know what you wanted to do to be able to give you better answers.

Answer (score 3):

Literals can't be used as "prefix expressions" to prefix `.name`, `[exp]` for assignments.

The workaround is to wrap literals in parentheses (for example: `("str"):rep(42)`).

In your case, you can *syntactically* fix your code by wrapping `nil` in parentheses:

```lua
(nil).Text = randomJokes.value
```

which most likely is nonsense *semantically*, unless someone did

```lua
debug.setmetatable(nil, {__newindex = function(_, key, value) ... end})
```

What did you intend to achieve?